# GML file provides wrong coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, gml

I have the following field 51A.[image]
It is described by the following GML excerpt:

```
<gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:av_export_temp.ihkulroo fid="av_export_temp.ihkulroo.183">
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>-63613.5803279425,6594849.11111532 -63338.4982627596,6596691.79998076 -61065.5082310117,6596353.15340253 -58792.3850046138,6596015.89007513 -56519.1291541683,6595680.00990826 -54245.7412499302,6595345.51281189 -51972.2218618083,6595012.39869636 -52241.6978222727,6593169.17366796 -54516.3382854795,6593502.39409221 -56790.8473374676,6593836.99795894 -59065.2244085927,6594172.98535813 -61339.468928864,6594510.35638005 -63613.5803279425,6594849.11111532</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></ogr:geometryProperty>
      <ogr:Copyright>Fishdirectory</ogr:Copyright>
      <ogr:Zone>51A</ogr:Zone>
      <ogr:County>Rogaland</ogr:County>
      <ogr:Timereport1>2018/09/11</ogr: Timereport1 >
      <ogr:Timereport2>2019/08/31</ogr:Timereport2>
    </ogr:av_export_temp.ihkulroo>
  </gml:featureMember>
  <gml:featureMember>
```

When I looked into GML file and QGIS CSR properties, it says that it uses EPSG:25832 ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N.

If I [transform](https://epsg.io/transform?fbclid=IwAR00lCyVn8Rhb9kw6TyTr3W7r3ZZOomBoc04_X_3K11OHIHl-ZUGXZjZxXU#s_srs=25832&t_srs=4326&x=-63613.5803279&y=6594849.1111153) the first coordinate point (-63613.5803279425,6594849.11111532) and then display it on the Google map, it is somewhere in the North Sea, but it should be somewhere around (59.130778, 5.241507) (taken from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Geitungane/@59.1284807,5.2378622,15.39z/data=!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x0:0x0!2zNTbCsDE0JzA3LjgiTiAxwrA1NCcxNi44IkU!3b1!8m2!3d56.2355102!4d1.9046687!3m4!1s0x463ba9b20fca9505:0xf386a61089a1a175!8m2!3d59.1316604!4d5.2440334)). What am I missing here?

Comment: It looks like those points are expressed in UTM 33N, not UTM 32N. I would try assigning  EPSG:25833 ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N, and see if it lines up properly.

Comment: can you include the part of the GML that expresses the srs?